# How to get web UI information like "Summary Metrics for Completed Tasks" in Stages tab programmatically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-webui

I want to get "Summary Metrics for Completed Tasks" in my scala code. This information can be found in the Spark webUI:

[image: a screenshoot of spark webUI page]

Answer (score 1):

web UI is just a bunch of [SparkListeners](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) that hold state and offer many helpful statistics about the state of Spark application.

That's why the driver fairly often needs more memory than you could expect -- for the internal state of web UI.

### SparkListener

> I want to get "Summary Metrics for Completed Tasks" in my Scala code.

Write your own `SparkListeners` and intercept events of your liking.

For "Summary Metrics for Completed Tasks"-like statistics you'd have to review the [source code of Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/jobs/StagePage.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L555) and step back to see what and how the Summary Metrics internal state is built.

### REST API

You could also access "Summary Metrics for Completed Tasks" data programmatically using REST API that is exposed at http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[appId]/stages.

The data you want is "Stage data" and is available per stage using `stageId` path param and `details` query param, i.e.

```
http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[appId]/stages/[stageId]?details
```

or

```
http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[appId]/stages/[stageId]?details=true
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You provide two solutions, the first is to add my own `SparkListeners` which seems difficult for me. The second way is to use REST API. Do you mean getting those infos from web pages directly? I will try this way. Thank you again!

Comment: _"Do you mean getting those infos from web pages directly?"_ No, quite the  contrary, i.e. the information will come to you.